# Get linq to xml descendants Elements with specific attribute value

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-xml

From a [twitter atom feed](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) I'm trying to get some feed data using linqToXml:

```
atomFeed = XDocument.Load(feedUrl);  
var tweets = (from entry in atomFeed.Descendants("entry")
                         select new
                         {
                             Date = entry.Element("published").Value,
                             Title = entry.Element("title").Value,
                             Url = entry.Element("link").Value // with type="image/jpeg"
                         }
                        );
```

Since there are two link types (one with attribute type="text/html" and one with type="image/jpeg" it doesn't work. I only need the link with the jpeg, but no clue how to extract only that link from the xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided there is exactly one link with type "image/jpeg" (and it looks that way from the samples):

```
Url = entry.Elements("link")
           .Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "image/jpeg")
           .Value;
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! For other people who are using this for their twitter feed: use the attribute rel = "image", because the type can also be png, etc.